# LINQ How to force query to materialize?

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have simple LINQ extenstion:

```
var filtered = data.Where(i => i.Count > 0);
```

I know that this will not evaluated unless I start to use *filtered* i.e.

```
foreach(DataItem i in filtered) ...
```

However I need to create cloned version of `data` and release data as soon as possible. `data` can be changed in other thread so I want to get immediate snapshot of it.

How can I force `filtered` to be evaluated immediately?

Comment: You mean the contents of the data will change (items addred/removed), or the individual items will have their properties changed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var filtered = data.Where(i => i.Count > 0).ToArray();

// or

var filtered = data.Where(i => i.Count > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: In what circumstances would i want to use `ToArray` as opposed to `ToList`?

Comment: IIRC `ToList()` might be quicker so you'd only use `ToArray()` if you actually need and array.

Answer (score 8):

To get a list populated with the result of the enumeration, call `ToList()`, i.e.,

```
var filtered = data.Where(i => i.Count > 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

To side-effect the sequence:

```
var filtered = data.Where(i => i.Count > 0).Run();
```

You may want to explore [Reactive Extension for .NET 3.5/4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx).