# How to write query where condition in List of shorts

Tags: c#, linq

I have to write a query using C# / LINQ, the equivalent of this:

```
select RoleName from dbo.Roles where RoleId in (2,3,4,5,6)
```

In my code I have a list of short ids (idRoles is a list of shorts ( example: 1,2,3,4)) and this code:

```
 List<string> roleNameList = new List<string>();

 roleNameList = _dbContext
  .Roles
  .Where(r => idRoles.Contains(r.RoleId))
  .Select(r => r.RoleName);
```

gives an error:

Cannot convert from System.Linq.IQueryable '<'string'>' to string.

But in my table Role the IdRole is a short(smallint)

Comment: What is the type of the `idRoles`?

Comment: What are the actual types being used?  I assume they're not actually called `type1` and `type2`?  Is it specifically the `.Contains()` operation producing the error?  What is the exact error?  What is the type of `idRoles`?  What is the type of `r.RoleId`?  How does either of them differ from what you expect?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show all code necessary to recreate the error. Also make sure the error is exactly the error you receive; I'm guessing the error you get does not mention "type1" or "type2", but rather includes the actual type names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ How to force query to materialize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057709/linq-how-to-force-query-to-materialize)

Comment: `Select` returns an `IEnumerable` and you try to put it in a `List`. Add `.ToList()` at the end of your query or change roleNameList type to `var` or `IEnumerable<string>`. As @serge answer

Comment: You can "put" a `List` inside of an `IEnumerable` but not the contrary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
List<string> roleNameList = _dbContext
  .Roles
  .Where(r => idRoles.Contains(r.RoleId))
  .Select(r => r.RoleName)
  .ToList();
```